# How does change in electric flux leads to production of charge?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I was doing questions related to *Gauss Theorem* and then I came across a question which was as follows:
If the amount of electric flux entering and leaving an enclosed surface respectively are $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, the electric charge inside the surface will be?

My question is that if the surface contains some charge enclosed then shouldn't $\phi_1=\phi_2$? How can number of field lines change if the surface area is same? Why will $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be different?

Comment: The charges produce electric flux not inversely.

Comment: Hint - Here there are two kinds of electric fields, one due to external sources(for eg charges present outside the surface) and second due to charge inside the surface.